# OpenCV: findHomography generating an empty matrix

Tags: c++, opencv, visual-studio-2012

When using `findHomography()`:

```
Mat H = findHomography( obj, scene, cv::RANSAC , 3, hom_mask, 2000, 0.995 );
```

Sometimes, for some image, the resulting H matrix stays empty (H is a UINT8, 1x0x0). However, there is clearly a match between both images (and it looks like good keypoint matches are detected), and just a moment before, with two similar images with similar keypoint responses, a relevant matrix was generated. Input parameters "obj" and "scene" are both a vector of `Point2f` containing various coordinates.

Is this a common issue? Or do you think a bug might lurk somewhere? Personally, I have processed hundreds of images where a match exists and while I have seen sometime poor matches, it is the first time I get an empty matrix...

**EDIT :** This said, even if my eyes think that there should be a match in the image pairs, I realize that it might confuses some portion of the image with an other one and that maybe there is indeed no "good" match.

So my question would be: How does `findHomography()` behave when it is unable to find a suitable Homography? Does it return an empty matrix or will it always give a homography, albeit a very poor one? I just want to know if I encounter standard behaviour or if there is a bug in my own code.

Comment: Could you upload your image here?

Comment: While I know this might reduce my chances to get an answer, I am not allowed to show the images for the moment. I added a precision to the question, though...

Comment: Maybe you can upload your keypoints and descriptors of your image somewhere instead of uploading your original image. btw, you can find implementation of OpenCV findHomography [here](https://github.com/Itseez/opencv/blob/master/modules/calib3d/src/fundam.cpp) and RANSAC method [here](https://github.com/Itseez/opencv/blob/master/modules/calib3d/src/ptsetreg.cpp) at line 161

Comment: Oh thanks stupidly I compiled OpenCV from Github but didn't think to look for the source code there... I guess I'll have my answer here. Thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Well you see, `cv::findHomography()` function could return empty homography matrix (0 cols x 0 rows) starting approximately from 2.4.5 release.
According to some opinion this seems happen only when `cv::RANSAC` flag is passed.

See the issue reported [here](http://code.opencv.org/issues/3057):

> It likely happened because we put in new experimental version of
>   Levenberg-Marquardt solver, which does not work that well (maybe due
>   to some bugs)

I suggest to check the computed homography before using it anywhere:

```
cv::Mat h = cv::findHomography(...)
if (!h.empty())
{
    // Use it
}
```

Comment: Thanks! And now I will take the habit to look at the bug report zone too in my searches!

Comment: This is now part of the [documentation](https://docs.opencv.org/3.3.0/d9/d0c/group__calib3d.html#ga4abc2ece9fab9398f2e560d53c8c9780): "Note that whenever an H matrix cannot be estimated, an empty one will be returned."